# protractor cucumber framework - inspite of defining stepdefination file , still shows suggestion to implement stepdefination

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

Hi I am new to this framework  - protractor-cucumber framewor [custom]
I struck in middle of my code.
version details:
protractor:5.4.0
cucumber:4.2.1
protractor-cucumber-framework:6.0.0
npm:5.6.0
Executing the code in eclipes:
unable to get what actually the issue is...Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks..

```html
My feature file:-----
Feature: Testing Calculator application
Scenario: Addition 
Given I browse to homepage
When I enter first number and second number
And I click on go button
Then I should see the result

Config file:------------------
exports.config = {
 seleniumAddress : 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
 framework : 'custom',
 baseURI: "http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/",
 frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
 specs : [ '../features/test.feature' 
 ],
 /*allScriptsTimeout: 380000,
   getPageTimeout: 20000,*/
   cucumberOpts : {
    require: ['../features/step_definitions/stepDefinitions.js'
   ]  
 },
 onPrepare : function() {
  browser.manage().window().maximize();
   }
};

stepdefination file-------------
var { Before, Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber');
module.exports=function(){
 var url="http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/";
 browser.get(url);
 Given('I browse to homepage', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  browser.get(url);
           return 'pending';
         });
 
 When('I enter first number and second number', function () {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     return 'pending';
   });
 
 Then('I should see the result', function () {
     // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
     return 'pending';
   });
};

Error recieved----------------------------------------------
[16:23:08] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:23:08] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[33mU[39m[33mU[39m[33mU[39m[33mU[39m[32m.[39m

Warnings:

1) Scenario: Addition # [90mfeatures\test.feature:2[39m
   [33m? Given I browse to homepage[39m
       [33mUndefined. Implement with the following snippet:[39m

       [33m  Given('I browse to homepage', function () {[39m
       [33m    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions[39m
       [33m    return 'pending';[39m
       [33m  });[39m
       [33m[39m
   [33m? When I enter first number and second number[39m
       [33mUndefined. Implement with the following snippet:[39m

       [33m  When('I enter first number and second number', function () {[39m
       [33m    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions[39m
       [33m    return 'pending';[39m
       [33m  });[39m
       [33m[39m
   [33m? And I click on go button[39m
       [33mUndefined. Implement with the following snippet:[39m

       [33m  When('I click on go button', function () {[39m
       [33m    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions[39m
       [33m    return 'pending';[39m
       [33m  });[39m
       [33m[39m
   [33m? Then I should see the result[39m
       [33mUndefined. Implement with the following snippet:[39m

       [33m  Then('I should see the result', function () {[39m
       [33m    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions[39m
       [33m    return 'pending';[39m
       [33m  });[39m
       [33m[39m
   [32m√ After[39m # [90mnode_modules\protractor-cucumber-framework\lib\resultsCapturer.js:25[39m

1 scenario ([33m1 undefined[39m)
4 steps ([33m4 undefined[39m)
0m00.000s
[16:23:13] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[16:23:13] I/launcher - chrome #01 passed
```

[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QI4v5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its your file and folder name issue. please rename your step definition folder and file name as "step_definitions" and "stepDefinitions.js" respectively.